# Why is the mousedown event being fired after click instead of during?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mousedown, mouseup

I have a div class "guessed" and have a timer to detect whether a short press and long press. When testing, the console logs "MOUSEDOWN" after the press instead of on the press.

The console also logs "SHORT PRESS" even if it's held for longer than 2 seconds.

I've tested the code on JSFiddle and it's working fine. However within my website, the code doesn't work. Can anyone spot the error? Many thanks

```js
var timer = 0;
var timerInterval;

$(document).on('mousedown', '.guessed', function() {
  console.log("MOUSEDOWN");
  timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
    timer += 1;
  }, 300);
});

$(document).on('mouseup', '.guessed', function() {
  if (timer < 1) {
    console.log("SHORT PRESS");
    clearInterval(timerInterval);
    timer = 0;
    return;
  }

  console.log("LONG PRESS");
  clearInterval(timerInterval);
  timer = 0;
});
```

```css
.guessed { border:1px solid red; width:100px; height:100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='guessed'>mouse me</div>
```

Comment: IMHO this should really not be done using setInterval and a custom "timer" counter. Create a new Date instance in the mousedown handler, a second one in the mouseup handler - and then check what the difference between those is in milliseconds.

Comment: *I've tested the code on JSFiddle and it's working fine* - so what's different in your code and in the fiddle?  In isolation, the code works fine, so there must be something added on your page that stops it working, which we can't see.  Different includes?  Different version of jquery?  Different classes? Errors in the console?  Maybe just the events are around the wrong way in your other code? I've converted your code to a snippet (which, obviously, works fine) - please update so we can see it *not working*.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use html attributes for `mouseup` and `mousedown` events and call custom defined JavaScript functions just like in the following example :

```js
var timer = 0,timerInterval;

function mousedownfunction() {
    console.log("MOUSE DOWN");
    timerInterval = setInterval(function() {
        timer += 1;
    }, 300);
}

function mouseupfunction() {
    console.log("MOUSE UP");
 
    if (timer < 1) {
        console.log("SHORT PRESS");

        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        timer = 0;
        return;
    } else {
        console.log("LONG PRESS");
        clearInterval(timerInterval);
        timer = 0;
        return;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="guessed" onmousedown="mousedownfunction()" onmouseup="mouseupfunction()">
    <p>Mouse</p>
</div>
```